# How to load additional modules when Xen hypervisor is loaded?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, xen

I'm currently running Debian 10 with Xen 4.12 installed.
I compiled Xen from source on another machine with the below steps:

1. ./configure --target=x86_64 --with-platform=efi --enable-systemd
2. make world
3. make dist
4. make debbal

After that I installed the Xen package on the Debian 10 host.
Furthermore I compiled a Vanilla kernel (5.3.8) and installed on the Debian 10 host as well.

Now everything is fine, but with the Xen hypervisor loaded, additional modules like coretemp cannot be loaded:

```
root@xen1:/# modprobe coretemp
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'coretemp': No such device
```

```
root@xen1:/# uname -a
Linux xen1 5.3.8 #1 SMP Wed Nov 6 13:42:42 CET 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
root@xen1:/# ll /usr/lib/modules/5.3.8/kernel/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.ko 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24872 Nov  6 13:41 /usr/lib/modules/5.3.8/kernel/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.ko
```

When booting the host without Xen hypervisor, I'm able to load the coretemp module without any problems.

Is there anything wrong with the configuration (maybe grub)?
Please find below my current grub configuration:

```
root@xen1:/# cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen hypervisor"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
set root='lvmid/bvbEzC-juKi-DnNc-yxrz-7KHu-uh1P-n6EPWK/tkAuXS-e4Gq-DY98-kkIY-nNf3-4fxn-u8QT2G'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/bvbEzC-juKi-DnNc-yxrz-7KHu-uh1P-n6EPWK/tkAuXS-e4Gq-DY98-kkIY-nNf3-4fxn-u8QT2G'  988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/08_linux_xen ###
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen hypervisor' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-simple-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
    fi
    echo    'Loading Xen 4.12.2-pre ...'
        if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
            xen_rm_opts=
        else
            xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
        fi
    multiboot2  /xen-4.12.2-pre.gz placeholder  dom0_mem=2560M,max:2560M ${xen_rm_opts}
    echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.8 ...'
    module2 /vmlinuz-5.3.8 placeholder root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro  quiet pcie_aspm=force
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-5.3.8
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux (with Xen hypervisor)' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
    submenu 'Xen hypervisor, version 4.12.2-pre' $menuentry_id_option 'xen-hypervisor-4.12.2-pre-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.12.2-pre and Linux 5.3.8' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-5.3.8-advanced-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
            insmod part_gpt
            insmod ext2
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
            fi
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.12.2-pre ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /xen-4.12.2-pre.gz placeholder  dom0_mem=2560M,max:2560M ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.8 ...'
            module2 /vmlinuz-5.3.8 placeholder root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro  quiet pcie_aspm=force
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-5.3.8
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.12.2-pre and Linux 5.3.8 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-5.3.8-recovery-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
            insmod part_gpt
            insmod ext2
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
            fi
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.12.2-pre ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /xen-4.12.2-pre.gz placeholder  ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.8 ...'
            module2 /vmlinuz-5.3.8 placeholder root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro single 
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-5.3.8
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.12.2-pre and Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-4.19.0-6-amd64-advanced-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
            insmod part_gpt
            insmod ext2
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
            fi
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.12.2-pre ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /xen-4.12.2-pre.gz placeholder  dom0_mem=2560M,max:2560M ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 ...'
            module2 /vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64 placeholder root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro  quiet pcie_aspm=force
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-4.19.0-6-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.12.2-pre and Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-4.19.0-6-amd64-recovery-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
            insmod part_gpt
            insmod ext2
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
            fi
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.12.2-pre ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /xen-4.12.2-pre.gz placeholder  ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 ...'
            module2 /vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64 placeholder root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro single 
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-4.19.0-6-amd64
        }
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/08_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.8 ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-5.3.8 root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro  quiet pcie_aspm=force
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initrd.img-5.3.8
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.3.8' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.8-advanced-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.8 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-5.3.8 root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro  quiet pcie_aspm=force
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-5.3.8
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.3.8 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.8-recovery-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.8 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-5.3.8 root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-5.3.8
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-6-amd64-advanced-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro  quiet pcie_aspm=force
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-4.19.0-6-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-6-amd64-recovery-988e72e2-cc10-46d6-9cd8-3b58827fe864' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e9e6e232-aef7-4e2e-ac20-cd8b218952b1
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-4.19.0-6-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

The /boot folder contains the following files:

```
root@xen1:/# ll /boot/
total 74084
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   206243 Sep 20 12:51 config-4.19.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   219726 Nov  6 13:41 config-5.3.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1638 Nov  5 09:37 config-xen-4.12.2-pre
drwx------ 3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Nov  6 15:08 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28041914 Nov  5 15:10 initrd.img-4.19.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28213404 Nov  6 14:45 initrd.img-5.3.8
drwx------ 2 root root    16384 Nov  5 13:32 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3409486 Sep 20 12:51 System.map-4.19.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3622883 Nov  6 13:41 System.map-5.3.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5262576 Sep 20 12:51 vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5548416 Nov  6 13:41 vmlinuz-5.3.8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1176799 Nov  5 10:00 xen-4.12.2-pre.gz
```

Some further details from syslog:

```
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Inserted module '8021q'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Failed to insert module 'coretemp': No such device
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Inserted module 'nct6775'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Inserted module 'xen_evtchn'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Inserted module 'xen_gntdev'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Inserted module 'xen_gntalloc'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Inserted module 'xen_blkback'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Inserted module 'xen_netback'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Inserted module 'xen_pciback'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Failed to find module 'evtchn'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Failed to find module 'gntdev'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Failed to find module 'netbk'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Failed to find module 'blkbk'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Failed to find module 'xen-scsibk'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Failed to find module 'usbbk'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Failed to find module 'pciback'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Inserted module 'xen_acpi_processor'
Nov  7 09:17:48 xen1 systemd-modules-load[228]: Failed to find module 'blktap2'
```

Comment: I think the driver need to be a front-end driver? Possibly something with paravirtualization?

Comment: Hint: Grub is loading XEN, whereas your kernel is just a parameter to xen.

Answer (score 0):

XEN is a bare metal Hypervisor.
Your Dom0 is a PV (paravirtualized) XEN VM (virtual machine).

As such the hypervisor takes care of the hardware - not your Dom0.
So hardware modules will not work - since the Dom0 has no hardware.

It is a virtual machine. You have to use XEN-parameters or tell xen something if you wish to change hardware relevant things.

As a priviledged VM the Dom0 will be able to pass some things to the hypervisor that other unprivileged VMs (DomUs) wont be able to do.